# Disable points of interest from google geocode

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I'm using google geocode like this

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Houston`

What I want is to disable the points of interest and/or establishments e.g.

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=greater boston area`

```
"formatted_address": "2 Copley Pl Ste 105, Boston, MA 02116, United States",
"place_id": "ChIJ88_4lQ1644kRniYQY54X0Og",
"types": [
   "establishment",
   "point_of_interest",
   "travel_agency"
]
```

I expected the above to have the below as a result (which is the result I get for `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=boston`)

```
"formatted_address": "Boston, MA, USA",
"place_id": "ChIJGzE9DS1l44kRoOhiASS_fHg",
"types": [
   "locality",
   "political"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like "greater X area" won't match a city named "X", because "greater" and "area" are not part of the city name/s. Instead, you get an establishment that does match the extra terms, e.g. ChIJ88_4lQ1644kRniYQY54X0Og is the place_id of 
Greater Boston Convention & Visitors Bureau:
https://www.google.com/maps?cid=0x89e37a0d95f8cff3:0xe8d0179e6310269e

Maybe you'd prefer Autocomplete, which does allow you to restrict results to geocodes (incl. cities) or addresses (excl. cities), both of which exclude establishments. Try it out here:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-autocomplete